# Invalid Form key.Please refresh the page

Tags: magento2, product, redirect, form-key, staging

If I visit my website first time it give me an error of Invalid form key.Please try again lator.
It is giving same error while add product in the cart and it directs the page to the Home page in browser Mozilla,Safari and Chrome.

I did a following changes to resolve this issue in Admin.
**Store->Configuration->Advanced->System->Full Page Cache.**
It resolved the issue for short time.When I visit same after5-6 hours it gives me same error on the staging server.
[image]

Please specify the best solutions of this issue.

Comment: you use the localhost ??

Comment: No I am using the live server.

Comment: you see this link second number method :- https://www.tigren.com/magento-error-invalid-form-key/ and any query let me know.. 2> https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Programming/Can-t-login-to-admin-quot-Invalid-Form-Key-Please-refresh-the/td-p/34434

Comment: This query is only recommend for the admin backend "DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_domain';".
Will it reflect changes on the frontend also ?
I have this issue on the Magento 2.3 version.

Comment: you means your issues us frontend and backend ??

Comment: My issue comes only on frontend when I add product in the cart in browser safari,chrome sometime in Mozilla also.
Suppose user visit the website and leave it for 4-5 hours.He cames back and try to add the product the cart it give an error Invalid form key.
I hope you better understand.

Comment: php.ini file you add this solutions ini_set('max_input_vars', 10000); ??

Comment: I have to set this condition on the server php.ini.I remembered I put limit to 15000 but it didn't work for me.

Comment: If I run this command DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_domain'; will it reflect changes on the frontend ?

Comment: yes,chnage the frontend and try this query